# Connection was forcibly closed by a peer - thunder client

Tags: vscode-extensions, mern, web-development-server, thunderclient

```
router.post("/orderData", async(req,res) => {
    let data = req.body.order_data;
    await data.splice(0,0, {order_date: req.body.order_date})

    let eId = await Order.findOne({ "email": req.body.email});
    if(eId === null){
        try {
            await Order.create({
                email: req.body.email,
                order_data: [data]
            }).then(() => {
                res.json({success : true});
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
            res.send("Server error" , error.message);
        }
    }

    else{
        try {
            await Order.findOneAndUpdate({ email: req.body.email} ,
                { $push: {order_data: data} }).then(() => {
                    res.json({success: true});
                })
        } catch (error) {
            res.send("Server error" , error.message);
        }
    }

})
```

In the above code , when I run the route /orderData in thunder client , I get a prompt saying "Connection was forcibly stopped by a peer" . Please help me to fix this.